# WIREMOCK Request Not Matched. HTTP Method and URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock

I am working with WIREMOCK to write some tests. I get the below error when I execute test case.

Request was not matched

```
Closest stub   | Request                                                  
GET              | CONNECT   <<<<< HTTP method does not match                                       
/greeting        | null      <<<<< URL does not match
```

This is my code.

```
public class HelloTest {
    @Autowired
    HelloDao HelloDao;
    @Test
    void testMethod() {
        String jsonResponse = """
                {
                   "version": {
                     "id": 22
                   }
                 }
                """;
        WIREMOCK.stubFor(get("/greeting").willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .withBody(jsonResponse)));
        var response = assertInstanceOf(HelloResp.class, HelloDao.getGreeting());
    }
}


public HelloResp getGreeting() {
    CompletableFuture<HelloResp> future = HelloAsyncDao.getGreeting();
    return ExternalApiUtils.joinFuture(future, HelloProperties.VERSION_API);
}

public CompletableFuture<HelloResp> getGreeting() {
    String urlPart = "/greeting";
    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.builder(urlPart).get().addHeaders(generateHttpHeaders()).build();
    return httpService.execute(httpRequest, helloProperties.getHttp(),HelloProperties.VERSION_API, HelloResponseMapper::mapHelloRespResp);
}
```

I changed the URI and tried some trial and error methods.
I am not sure how this error happens as I am quite new to WIREMOCK. A help would be much appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set wiremock before and use spring boot test annotations. Here is a working example:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
abstract class UserControllerIntegrationTestSupport {

  WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(3000);


@Autowired protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @BeforeEach
  void setupBeforeEach() throws Exception {

     
      List<UserDTO> mockUserDTOs =
        Arrays.asList(
            new UserDTO(1L, "User1", "user1@example.com", "username1"),
            new UserDTO(2L, "User2", "user2@example.com", "username2"));

    RestPageResponse<UserDTO> pageResponse = new RestPageResponse<>(mockUserDTOs);

    String jsonResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pageResponse);


    // wiremock setup

    wireMockServer.start();

    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port());
    stubFor(
        get(urlEqualTo("/mock/user"))
            .willReturn(
                aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").withBody(jsonResponse)));
  }

  @AfterEach
  void tearDownAfterEach() {
    
    wireMockServer.stop();
  }
```

l

Comment: Thank you for your reply gurkan. The configurations are not a problem since other test methods of the same class works fine. I did not include the configuration details since those are not relevant.

Comment: i could not see where did you set WireMock. can you please add wiremock configs? we dont know that did you started wiremock or not. maybe its null

Comment: I extend this class in my test class. I am certain that there is no problem because other tests run fine with the same configuration. Thank you for your support Gurkan :)

public abstract class WiremockConfig {
    @RegisterExtension
    protected static final WireMockExtension WIREMOCK = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
            .options(options().port(9100)).build();